# OpenLDAP pwdPolicySubentry for organizationalUnit

Tags: openldap, password-policy

Can you set a pwdPolicySubentry for an organizationalUnit, so that all entries contained in that organizationalUnit follow that password policy?

Comment: Try it and see? (The documentation seems to imply "No", but it's not clear...)

Answer (score 1):

No. It has to be set on each entry separately,